# ID in out edge in gremlin

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have edge between two vertices 
8392 ---> 532500664 with label "has" 
still

```
g.V(8392).out("has").has("id",532500664)
```

is not working
Tell me how to achieve this?

Note = g is a graph traversal object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume "532500664" is the actual identifier for the Vertex as in the return value of `Vertex.id()` and not something you assigned yourself as a property called "id". If that is the case, your `has("id",532500664)` is incorrect as it is trying to do a lookup for the latter. You would instead want to do:

```
g.V(8392).out("has").has(T.id,532500664)
```

or if you are in the Gremlin Console or you statically imported `T` then:

```
g.V(8392).out("has").has(id,532500664)
```

which you will commonly see in the TinkerPop documentation.

Comment: Just to add to Stephen's answer you can also use the shorthand `hasId(123)` rather than `has(T.id, 123)`;

Comment: Thank you Stephen & Filipe
It was too much useful